# Appending json object inside the main block in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a json file from python. I have the following code:

```
import json

PARENTS = ["parent1", "parent2"]
data = []
for parent in PARENTS:
    data.append(
                    {
                        parent:
                        {
                            "child1": "value1",
                            "child2": "value2"
                        }
                    }
                )
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

The output of this is the following json. It creates 2 separate blocks.

```
[
    {
        "parent1": {
            "child1": "value1",
            "child2": "value2"
        }
    },
    {
        "parent2": {
            "child1": "value1",
            "child2": "value2"
        }
    }
]
```

However I need the output within a single block like below:

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "value1",
        "child2": "value2"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "value1",
        "child2": "value2"
    }
}
```

How can I get it in the format I need. Thanks!

Comment: make data a dict instead of a list, then set the value of data based on the parent you iterate through

Answer (score 1):

make data a dict instead of a list and set the parent value

```py
import json

PARENTS = ["parent1", "parent2"]
data = {}
for parent in PARENTS:
    data[parent] = {
                 "child1": "value1",
                 "child2": "value2"
    }

with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead of a list

```
import json

PARENTS = ["parent1", "parent2"]  
data = {}  
for parent in PARENTS:  
    data[parent]=\
                        {
                            "child1": "value1",
                            "child2": "value2"
                        }

             
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same in a single line.

```
data = {parent: {'child1':'value1', 'child2':'value2'} for parent in parents}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/

Do keep in mind that dict has unique immutable keys mapped to single value(unless you store list/dict against a key in the dict). **Ensure the parent strings are unique keys.** to avoid the value against a key being overridden in any way you use.